# how to change error class from div to span

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have this code

```
echo  $this->Form->control('password', array('class'=>"input-text ",'label'=>false));
```

and this for the error message

```
"inputContainer" => '{{content}}',
'inputContainerError' => '{{content}}{{error}}'
```

when there is an error, it generates the below code

```
<div class="error-message">Must be at least 4 characters long.</div>
```

I want to change the div element to span element as shown below

`<span class="error-message">Must be at least 4 characters long.</span>`

Anyone knows how to do it? thank you

Comment: If the answer below worked for you, you should mark it as accepted. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sould change 'error' key, like this:

```
'error' => '<span class="error-message">{{content}}</span>'
```

More about templates: https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/source-class-Cake.View.Helper.FormHelper.html#102-164